# Why would I want to use Worldclay?

Tags: demoncrawl

The description of Worldclay says

> Morphs into another artifact from your recipe. A recipe using Worldclay cannot unlock divine items.

As far as I can tell, unlocking divine items seems to be the main benefit of doing Beyond quests. So, why would I want to use Worldclay in a recipe if I can't unlock divine items?

Answer (score 1):

Two kinds of loot are found on specific stages: paint and relics. Beyond mode can be used to try to get those specific loot drops by using the corresponding relics. With Worldclay, 3 stages of a specific type can be created using just one relic.